# JS script comes out with website's error of invalid shipping method

Tags: javascript, web, e-commerce

Running a simple JS script for an auto checkout on friends website to test vulnerability

```html
var address = "1240 Loma Vista Dr";

document.getElementById("shipping:street1").value = address;
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function demo() {
  console.log('Taking a break...');
  await sleep(2000);
  console.log('Two seconds later');
}
document.getElementsByClassName("continue button")[1].click();
```

Here is an inspecting the elements of the websites button code just to make sure i didn't use `click()` improperly

```html
<button type="button" class="continue button validation-passed" title="Save and Continue" onclick="shipping.save();saveBilling();"><span><span>Save and Continue</span></span></button>
```

[image]

/\ shows error result from the site. Shows error message I'm getting from google chrome console when i run the code. the website gives me this error? but I'm 100% sure i entered valid shipping address. So why would it give me this error?

Answer (score 0):

Anyone have an idea on what's going on? :)